# Multi Div in same row no in another row

Tags: html, css

I want to put multiple divs in same line, but one always comes under the other one. What should I do?

View : https://jsfiddle.net/Alana2597/4pnakz8a/

```css
.content {
  width: 240px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div1">div2</div>
  <div id="div1">div3</div>
  <div id="div1">div4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet to show the issue. I only see two divs

Comment: Question is: "What have you tried?" Essentially, you need to ensure that the parent element is wide enough to allow the space required for nested elements to display inline without wrapping.

Comment: I think the OP **wants* the overflow scroll. That's the point here..although I could be wrong.

Comment: @mplungjan because the container width is only 240px

Comment: i need only 240px if more i need to scroll the div(.content). here the scroll is n't works.

Comment: I know - so we need a “expected behaviour “

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to apply `white-space:nowrap` to the parent.

This would **normally** solve the problem but the `float` on the children overrides this.

So you could with set these divs to `display:inline-block`

```css
.content {
  width: 240px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size:0; /* remove gap between divs */
}

.content div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:1rem; /* reset font size */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
  <div id="div4">div4</div>
</div>
```

Or perhaps use Flexbox

```css
.content {
  width: 240px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.content div {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
  <div id="div4">div4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `display:flex;`
Please check **[THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/6ks3k0v8/1/)** example

Note: Please dont use same id name for multiple elements

Example Code:

```
.content{
     width: 240px;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     max-height:100px;
     height:100px;
     display:flex;
   }
   .div1{
     height: 300px;
     min-width: 100px;
     border: solid 1px #000000;
     background-color: #0066CC;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you need to switch the ids to classes as ids are unique and as a result your markup is invalid.

Secondly you have specified `width: 240px` to `.content` and as a result its children don't have enough space and wrap. Switch `width: 240px` to `width: 100%` and it will work

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your divs in an additional container. Give this container a `width` value - something very wide...

```css
.content {
  width: 240px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-content {
  width: 1100000px;
}

#div1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div1">div2</div>
    <div id="div1">div3</div>
    <div id="div1">div4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```